# Input fields works strange in POST method

Tags: html, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I can't understand, why when I add the "password" div, my html view is not shown correctly? Using Thymeleaf as template engine.
HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Registration</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/PET/login}" th:object="${user}">
        <div>
            <label for="login">Enter your login</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{login}" id="login"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Enter your password</label>
            <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" id="password"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Enter your email</label>
            <input type="email" th:field="*{email}" id="email"/>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="create"/>
    
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**With password div**

[image]

**without password div**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Renaming my own setter/getter for password field helped, from get/setPass to get/setPassword. Forgot to change methods after small refractoring